# Can sealed trait contain Tuples?

Tags: scala

This sealed trait compiles :

```
sealed trait Tree[Int , String]
```

but if I use a Tuple :

```
sealed trait Tree[(Int , String)]
```

causes compiler error :

```
identifier expected but '(' found.
```

Are tuples a special case of sealed trait ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you declare

```
sealed trait Tree[Int, String]
```

It actually has nothing to do with the `Int` and `String` types. You are declaring type parameters called `Int` and `String` (i.e. they "shadow" `Int` and `String`). For example, this is a valid extension:

```
case object Pine extends Tree[Boolean, BigDecimal]
```

The compiler is complaining because you're using invalid syntax for declaring type parameters (parenthesis). It looks like you're trying to declare fixed type parameters, which makes no sense.

You'd get the same compile error by trying this with a def (or class or any trait):

```
def foo[(Int, String)](a: (Int, String)): Unit
```

Comment: is the reason "case object Pine extends Tree[Boolean, BigDecimal]" is valid due to type erasure ?

Comment: @blue-sky No, it's because `Int` does not refer to the type `Int`, it's just placeholder symbol. It's no different than declaring `Tree[A, B]`

Comment: so the types Int & String in "sealed trait Tree[Int, String]" are irrelevant, they are just placeholders to indicate that the type Tree accepts two type parameters of some type ?

Comment: Written like that, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Your original declaration (

```
trait Tree[Int, String]
```

) doesn't mean that the trait `Tree` takes parameters of `Int` and `String` in Scala.

If you want to declare a class that takes `Int` and `String`:

```
class Foo(i: Int, s: String)
```

If you need the class to be trait which cannot take parameters:

```
trait Foo {
  val i: Int
  val s: String
}
```